# how i retreive the post content while editing it in real time however the editor is tinymce or gutenberg

Tags: plugins, javascript, editor

I am developing a plugin, and I need to get the content of the editor of the post, whatever the type of editor is gutenberg or tinymce.
I hope that it is with javascript because I have a button action that must trigger this code.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you're trying to do, and maybe narrow the focus of your question to specifics about the code you're trying to implement?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, can you give us more context? What does your plugin do? Where/when are you trying to get the content of the post?

Comment: okay , my plugin get the text from the editor of the post admin panel and check the plagiarism before publishing the post , so i am trying to get the text inside my editor and send it to an api , but my problem is that if the editor is gutenberg or tinymce there is differenc in javascript code

Comment: So it must be a singular code that works for both gutenberg or tinymce editor .

Comment: there is no single API or function that will do that, and the user interfaces are wildly different. Even the code to put a button in the editor would be extremely different. You need 2 pieces of javascript, there is no universal solution